# How to make window size responsive in Electron. (On the opening of the app)

Tags: javascript, electron

I recently started making an app on Electron, I wanted to make the window responsive, for example, if I open app on different screens it should open in full-size according to the screen size.
my code:

```
  app.on('ready', () => {
      const htmlPath = path.join('src', 'html/login.html')
      mainWindow1 = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000 , height: 1000})
      mainWindow1.loadFile(htmlPath)

    })
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating your `BrowserWindow` you should call `maximize()`

```
mainWindow1 = new BrowserWindow();
mainWindow1.loadFile(htmlPath);
mainWindow1.maximize();
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winmaximize

Comment: is there any way to make the browser window responsive to the content of the window i.e. the width of the browser window grows when the width of `index.html` content grows?? i know you can use `remote` to access that sort of stuff from the renderer process

Comment: @oldboy I don't not know off hand about that.  I suggest you ask a new question for that.

Comment: [i already have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691032/browser-window-responsive-to-content/59691406#59691406) and the response has been underwhelming