# Browser Window Responsive to Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, responsive-design, electron, responsive

I cannot really find any questions or information related to this elsewhere, so I thought I would post a question. Is there a way to make the `BrowserWindow` responsive to the content of `index.html`?

I know you can likely do this by manually changing the size of the `BrowserWindow` either with `resizeTo` or `remote`, but you would need to know the explicit size to set it to.

Is there a way to simply make the window responsive to the content, so that as the document's `body` grows, so too does the window?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple approach to this could be: create a timer with **setTimeout** to check if document(**document.body**) size change; to this, use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method and a 'static function' variable storing the last size.

```js
function getDocumentWidth(){//returns current document width
  return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'), null).getPropertyValue("width");
}

function checkDocumentWidthChanged(callback){//verify by document width change, execute a callback function argument if it happened and resume the verification call
  let ns=getDocumentWidth()
  
  if(this.lastSize!=ns){
    this.lastSize=ns
    callback()
   }
   
   setTimeout(function(){checkDocumentWidthChanged(callback);}, 500);
   
}

checkDocumentWidthChanged.lastSize=getDocumentWidth();//function static var to store the last document size

checkDocumentWidthChanged(function(){//stat the loop
  console.log('New document size:'+checkDocumentWidthChanged.lastSize)
})

document.body.addEventListener('click',function(evt){//Set an event listener to test the proccess
  this.style.width=300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)+'px'
  console.log(this.style.width)
})
```

```html
<body>
Click here to change the document body size or change the browser size.
</body>
```

Comment: your approach would definitely work, but i can see it running into "issues", and i dont really like the idea of continually polling the doc to see if its changed size. thanks for the suggestion nonetheless