# how to adjust height and width of an app according to screen resolution

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I need to simplify electron display of an app where the app will shrink its size if the display is smaller for example Laptop display or Big size display like iMac. If the app is running on a laptop the size should be smaller than the actual size of an app. I tried `ZoomFactor` from `webPreference` API but It's not working as I expected.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can get the screen size first using the electron screen module,
First, import the electron screen module:

```js
import {screen} from 'electron'
```

Then on app.on ('ready') get the work area size of the screen:

```js
app.on('ready', async() => {
    primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay()
    console.log(primaryDisplay);
    let screenDimention = primaryDisplay.workAreaSize
    width = screenDimention.width
    height = screenDimention.height

    // I count my on scaleFactor here based on full HD 1920 because by default I designed my webContent on 1920 x 1080 (You can replace on your own)
    scaleFactor = 1 / (1920 / width);
    createWindow().finally(() => {
        console.log("#[Main Window] Created By 'onReady'");
        console.log("-------------------------------------------------------");
    });
})
```

Should note here that we actually could use

```
    primaryDisplay = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().scaleFactor
```

but based on my experience, this scale factor is not that correct especially for MacBook, and I could not get a custom scale factor for my default resolution 1920 x 1080, so I decide to count my own scale factor above.

The last step then you can set the zoom before show your main window like this:

```js
        mainWindow.webContents.setZoomFactor(scaleFactor);
```

Complete example code shown below:

```js
async function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        show: false,
        maximizable: true,
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        icon: path.join(__static, 'test.ico'),
        title: "Test",

        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
            devTools: isDevelopment,
            // enableRemoteModule: true,
            nativeWindowOpen: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        },
    })

    // Need to enable this one in electron>15.0
    // require("@electron/remote/main").enable(mainWindow.webContents);

    mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
        createTray()
        if (!isDevelopment) {
            //mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
            mainWindow.removeMenu();
            mainWindow.maximize();


        } else {
            mainWindow.maximize();
            mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
            mainWindow.removeMenu();
            mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
        }

        //Adjust zoom factor according to DPI or scale factor that we determined before
        console.log("Display with current scale factor: %o", scaleFactor);
        mainWindow.webContents.setZoomFactor(scaleFactor);
        mainWindow.show()

    });
```

If you need to shrink your window size based on screen size, then you could replace width and height like this:

```js
        /// 460 and 640 is your window size, it is totally up to you
             width: parseInt(460 * scaleFactor)
            height: parseInt(640 * scaleFactor)
```

Note that we should use parseInt, because width and height will not work for floating numbers.

This method works for me and it will try to show my original web content on 1920x1080 even on different screen resolutions like MacBook or fullHD windows with different scaling sizes or DPI. Hope it helps!

Comment: How is this not marked as the answer! Thank you so much for sharing this has helped me hugely!

Answer (score 0):

After creating your `BrowserWindow` you should call maximize()

```
mainWindow1 = new BrowserWindow();
mainWindow1.loadFile(htmlPath);
mainWindow1.maximize();
```

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winmaximize

Taken from - [How to make window size responsive in Electron. (On the opening of the app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034041/how-to-make-window-size-responsive-in-electron-on-the-opening-of-the-app)

Comment: It's not what I'm actually looking for my app is an fixed size app and not maximizable. so, it's located in fix portion of the screen. so, when I open it in smaller display or I can say smaller resolution display it'll get cut from top side.

Comment: It seems like you need diferent fixed sizes for different screen sizes. Get the screen size and have some logic based on width/height and adjust the app size.Your app size needs a minimum size and ideal size but should be usable in other resolutions maybe a % of screen size or min value (the max of those)

Comment: do you get an answer already?

Answer (score 0):

For your use case (if I understand it), you can use [screen](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/screen#screen) to determine the size of the screen at launch and then size the window appropriately.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen } = require('electron')

let win
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const { width, height } = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width, height })
  win.loadURL('https://github.com')
})
```

Comment: I'm having fixed width and height application window. so, It won't work in my case. I need to scale the application window size to low when It's running in a low-resolution system.

Comment: @HarshMakwana – I guess I don't understand then. You can preserve the aspect ratio when resizing by doing a little math so that the window proportions remain the same. FWIW – there is also a "resizeWindowContents" function too (not the exact name of it but that's what it does.). Anyway, good luck.